# how to copy the data of a user that is currently login from a data sheet to destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the data of the user that is currently login from a data sheet to a destination sheet.

Here is the code that i worked on for login:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetUserName() As String
    GetUserName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Range("userName").Value
End Function

Function GetPassword() As String
    GetPassword = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Range("passWord").Value
End Function

Function IsValidUser(u As String, p As String) As Boolean
    Dim vu As Variant
    Set vu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Range("listOfUsers").Find(u)
    If Not vu Is Nothing And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Cells(vu.Row, 
vu.Column + 1).Value = p Then IsValidUser = True Else IsValidUser = False
    Set vu = Nothing
End Function

Function IsLockedUser(u As String) As Boolean
    Dim vu As Variant
    Set vu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Range("listOfUsers").Find(u)
    If Not vu Is Nothing And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Cells(vu.Row, 
vu.Column + 2).Value = 0 Then IsLockedUser = True Else IsLockedUser = False
    Set vu = Nothing
End Function

Function GetNoOfAttempt() As Integer
    GetNoOfAttempt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Range("noOfAttempt").Value
End Function

Sub SetNoOfAttempt(a As Integer)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Range("noOfAttempt").Value = a
End Sub

Sub Login()
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim totAttempt As Integer
    totAttempt = GetNoOfAttempt

    If IsValidUser(GetUserName, GetPassword) Then
        If IsLockedUser(GetUserName) = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Activate
    Else
        LockUser GetUserName
        MsgBox GetMessage("userLocked"), vbExclamation, "Locked"
    End If
Else
    SetNoOfAttempt totAttempt - 1
    If GetNoOfAttempt > 0 Then
        MsgBox GetMessage("msgLoginFailed"), vbExclamation, "Failed"
    Else
        MsgBox GetMessage("maxAttempt"), vbExclamation, "Failed"
    End If
End If
Exit Sub
err:
MsgBox err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
End Sub


Sub LockUser(u As String)
Dim vu As Variant
Set vu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Range("listOfUsers").Find(u)
If Not vu Is Nothing Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Cells(vu.Row, vu.Column + 2).Value = 0
Set vu = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here are the sheeets that i am using:

Data Sheet
[image: Sheet1]

Destination Sheet
[image: Sheet2]

The purpose of this one is for update. So if the user want to change something to their data they can easily update in the destination sheet. then the save button should automatically update their data on the data sheet.

Comment: So what is the challenge that you are facing? Store your currently login user location (Row Number) at some place and use it to update your data in the datasheet. If any specific code is not working we may help...

Comment: hi @DhirendraKumar,  i would like to have that lets say the username admin is log in . then the destination sheet will gonna be populated by the data which is on the data sheet. so the password from data sheet will be on destination sheet and the security question1, 2, 3 and answer will be on populated on the destination sheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieved the output that i want. What i did is just create a new sheet then get the data from the data sheet that is equal to a username who log in. And then paste it the new sheet. After that i just equal the cells from the new sheet to the destination sheet.

Admin = Data Sheet

Profile = Destination Sheet

Consolidated = New Sheet

Here is the Code:

```
Sub Transfer_Consolidated()

path = "Admin"

sql = ""
sql = sql & "Select [Username], [Password], '', [Security Question 1], 
[Answer 1], [Security Question 2], [Answer 2], [Security Question 3], 
[Answer 
3]"
sql = sql & "From [Admin$C26:K54]"
sql = sql & "Where [Username] = '" & Sheet1.Range("userName").Value & "'"

Sheet = "Consolidated" '(New Sheet)

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Scrape path, sql, Sheet

Call Transfer_Profile

End Sub

Sub Transfer_Profile()


 Sheets("Profile").Range("E14").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!B2"

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E17").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!D2"

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E18").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!E2"

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E19").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!F2"

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E20").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!G2"

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E21").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!H2" '

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E21").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!H2"

 Sheets("Profile").Range("E22").Value = _
 "=Consolidated!I2"


End Sub
```